# Change width of ONE cell within table

Tags: html, layout, html-table, html-email

I'm laying out an email in table format and my goal is to resize the 'Learn More' without the rest of the row resizing. Something to the effect of the image provided:

[image: MOCK-UP].

I tried adding a width attribute, but it didn't work.

```
<table style="background-color: #a9cfee;">
    <tr style="border: none; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:white; font-size: 43px; text-align: left; ">
        <td>
            <strong>ELITE GROOMING TUB</strong>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="tub.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: none; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:white; font-size: 15px; text-align: left;">
            We have made our premium tub even better. Stairs are extra sturdy but lighter weight. With the flick of a foot, they slide underneath the tub.
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: none; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:white; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 800; background-color: #0033a0; width: 50%;">
            Learn More
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that I see the image, I'm completely revising my answer.

Your table structure is not going to display well the way you have it currently displaying.

For instance, you have a `<td rowspan="3">` for the tub row. You need to add in the the widths of the two cells in the first row to make things flow better.

The button was also controlling the width of the table. I put it's sizing into a seperate table within the cell so you can control the width of the button without influencing the width of the table.

Good luck.

```
<table style="background-color: #a9cfee;" border="1" width="580">
<tr style="border: none; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:white; font-size: 43px; text-align: left; ">
    <td width="80%">
        <strong>ELITE GROOMING TUB</strong>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3" width="20%">
        <img src="tub.png">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: none; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:white; font-size: 15px; text-align: left;">
        We have made our premium tub even better. Stairs are extra sturdy but lighter weight. With the flick of a foot, they slide underneath the tub.
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:white; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 800; text-align:center;">

      <table align="center" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td style="border: none; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:white; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 800; background-color: #0033a0; width:200px; text-align:center;">Learn More</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/53ucukpo/

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go. Keep your outside `<table>` at full width and next a second, more narrow `<table>` just for the button.